# Python returns only 2 different rows when it should return many more

Tags: python

Why on earth does this give me one different vector in row 1 and the same vectors for all other rows?

```
for i in range(0,c_number):
    for i in range(0,len(s_name)):
        if randint(1,101)>70:
            children[i] = alfa[randint(0,26)]
    CM.append([children])
    print(children)
    children=parent

CM=np.vstack(CM)
```

This is currently the result when I print CM after and children during:

```
['u', 's', 'y', 'h', 'l', 'g', 'e', 'd']
['u', 'w', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'g', 'n', 'b']
['u', 'k', 'h', 'c', 'h', 'g', 'n', 'b']
['u', 'i', 'h', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'j', 'b']
['u', 'c', 'h', 'y', 'h', 'g', 'j', 'b']
['u', 'v', 'j', 'r', 'h', 'g', 'd', 'b']
['y', 'v', 'j', 'r', 'h', 'g', 'd', 'b']
['y', 'v', 'j', 'r', 'h', 'g', 'd', 'b']
['y', 'n', 'j', 'f', 'o', 'q', 'd', 'b']
['v', 'n', 'j', 'f', 'o', 'q', 'd', 'b']
[['u' 's' 'y' 'h' 'l' 'g' 'e' 'd']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']
 ['v' 'n' 'j' 'f' 'o' 'q' 'd' 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it executes:

```
children=parent
```

it makes `children` refer to the same object (a list) as `parent`, which is reused in all the subsequent iterations.

Here's another example:

```
parent = []
children = parent
print(parent is children) # Prints True because they are the _same_ object
parent.append('parent')
print(parent) # Prints ['parent']
print(children) # Also prints ['parent']
```

Comment: Yeah that is also what I ended up figuring must happen, so how do I say children=parent without saying that parent is children?

Comment: Or essentially what I want is how do I take the information from parent and set children equal to that?

Comment: The simplest way to make a copy of a list is with slicing: `children = parent[:]`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `i` you have it twice in two different loops, make the second loop have a different variable like `j` or something

```
    #---v
    for i in range(0,c_number):
     for i in range(0,len(s_name)):
    #----^
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to fix it.

The only way to make it work is if I redefine children again as what it was originally. But then my other part doesn't work.

Comment: @user3481433: When do you want `CM.append([children])` to happen?  Currently it's being executed once per outer loop.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski +1, What I was going to say

Comment: I'd like it to happen once the for loop i in range (0,len(s_name)) has run its course.

Comment: Still have no idea whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out:

```
for j in range(0,c_number):
    for i in range(0,len(s_name)):
        if randint(1,101)>70:
            children[i] = alfa[randint(0,26)]
    CM.append([children])
    print(children)
    print(parent)
    children=parent[:]
```

This makes me only take the information from parent